# Unable to read file greater than 2K in FatFS

Tags: stm32, flash, freertos, stm32f10x

I am reading a file from the SPI Flash with FATFS file system, on STM32F103 platform running FreeRTOS. I can successfully read File of size less the 2048, but if read a file file of size greater than 2048, (As i am reading in chunks of 128 bytes) it only reads up to 2048 bytes and f_read returns 'FR_INT_ERR' error when File pointer move to location above 2048 bytes.

Below in my code for Read write test. f_size is show the correct file size. But when I read, it gives error, If I focefully run the loop till end of file for reading data it always returns the last chunk before 2048 bytes again and again.

```
FRESULT xRes;
FIL xFile;
const char cWBuffer[] = "Hello FAT World! 0123456789abcdef";
char cRBuffer[128]

xRes = f_mount(0, &s_xVolume);
printf("\r\n mount result %d successful!",xRes);

#ifdef FAT_MAKEFS_TEST
    // this delay is to prevent the FAT corruption after a systenm reset.
    Delay_us( 200 );

    printf("\r\n MAKE FS Test");
    printf("\r\n format the ext FLASH");
    printf("\r\n please wait...");
    xRes = f_mkfs(0, SFD_FORMAT, 4096 *10 );
    printf("\r\n Format result : %d ",xRes);
    assert(xRes == FR_OK);
#endif

#ifdef FAT_WRITE_TEST
    Delay_us( 1000 );

    printf("\r\n WRITE Test");
    printf("\r\n open file: W+CA");
    xRes = f_open(&xFile, filename, FA_WRITE|FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
    printf("\r\n Open result : %d ",xRes);
    assert(xRes == FR_OK);

    printf("\r\n write file");
    for(i=0;i<1024;i++)
    {
        xRes = f_write(&xFile, cWBuffer, strlen(cWBuffer), &n);
        //printf("\r\n Write result : %d, bytes = %d ",xRes,n);
        assert(xRes == FR_OK);
        //assert(n == strlen(cWBuffer));
    }

    printf("\r\n close file");
    xRes = f_close(&xFile);
    assert(xRes == FR_OK);

#endif

#ifdef FAT_READ_TEST
    Delay_us( 100 );

    printf("\r\n READ Test");
    printf("\r\n open file: R+OE");
    xRes = f_open(&xFile, filename, FA_READ|FA_OPEN_EXISTING);
    printf("\r\n Open result : %d ",xRes);
    assert(xRes == FR_OK);

    fs = f_size(&xFile);

    printf("\r\n read file size = %d",fs);
    i=0;
    fs = f_size(&xFile);
    while(i<fs)
    {
        xRes = f_read(&xFile, cRBuffer, sizeof(cRBuffer), &m);
        printf("\r\n Read result : %d, bytes read = %d, i =%d ",xRes,m,tread);
        tread += m;
        assert(xRes == FR_OK);
        //assert(m == strlen(cWBuffer));
    }
    printf("\r\n Total bytes read = %d",tread);
    printf("\r\n close file");
    printf("\r\n file content:");
    printf("%s :\n",cRBuffer);
    xRes = f_close(&xFile);
    assert(xRes == FR_OK);
#endif
printf("\r\n test success!!!");
```

Comment: You need to provide more info, pieces of code...

Comment: Dzarda, I have added the code snippet that may help....

Comment: It seems to be an INTernal ERRor. Maybe you could try to format the flash memory and try it again. An other option is to increase the stack size for this task; it is maybe running out of space.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to FreeRTOS f_read() call, but for some operating systems, f_read() can only read up the the boundary of the sector size of the underlying media, typically 512 or 2048 bytes. To read more data than that, the f_read() call would need to implement a gather function, reading data from multiple sectors.

We've seen this behavior in nuttx, and I suspect FreeRTOS does the same. To read a larger file, try reading it in blocks sized to your media.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem might be that you have the same instruction "fs = f_size..." twice.  One before and one after the print read file instruction.  If this is not the problem, then where are you getting the "file size" information?